# Balls in Bins with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, balls-in-bins

The question is as follows:

> In how many ways can $30$ balls be placed into $10$ bins. The restriction is that any bin can only contain $0$, $2$, $3$ or $5$ balls. The balls are identical and the bins are identical.

This formula can be used, but how can it be adjusted to account for the restrictions?

$$\binom{n - 1}{k - 1}$$

In addition the problem can be restated to this Diophantine equation with three variables:

$$2x_1 + 3x_2 + 5x_3 = 30$$

Edit:

Evaluating the coefficient of $x^{30}$ in the generating function $(1 + x^2)^{10}(1+x^3)^{10}(1+x^5)^{10}$ gives $5630506$ which does not make sense.

Comment: Please first clarify whether the balls are distinct or identical, and whether the bins are distinct or identical.

Comment: Are you sure that the bins are identical? If so then stars and bars should not be used here. Rather you should consider finding number of partitions of 30.

Comment: I tried using partitions of 30 using generating functions but it overcounted. How should I continue?

Comment: @Triple_1 Your two approaches work for identical objects and distinct bins, so they are not applicable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us first study the given equation,
$2a+3b+5c=30$. I'm setting $x_1=a, x_2=b, x_3=c$. Taking modulo $2,3,5$ $$b\equiv c \mod 2 $$ $$ a+c \equiv 0 \mod 3$$ $$a \equiv b \mod 5$$

Meaning,

1. $a,b$ give same remainder on division by $5$
2. $b,c$ are simultaneously odd or even
3. $a,c$ are both multiples of $3$ or if $a$ gives remainder $1$ then $c$ gives remainder $2$ on division by $3$.
4. Also note $a+b+c \le 10$.

I made following table on two cases : $a$ is odd or even.
First using $\# 1$ that $a,b$ give same remainder by $5$, I filled in as follows,
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c} \hline
a & b & c &  & a & b & c \\ \hline
1 & 1 &   &  & 0 & 0 &   \\  
  & 6 &   &  &   & 5 &   \\  
  &   &   &  &   & 10 &   \\ \hline
3 & 3 &   &  & 2 & 2 &   \\  
  & 8 &   &  &   & 7 &   \\ \hline
5 & 0 &   &  & 4 & 4 &   \\  
  & 5 &   &  &   & 9 &   \\  
  & 10 &   &  &   &   &   \\ \hline
7 & 2 &   &  &  6 & 1 &   \\  
  & 7 &   &  &   &  6 &   \\ \hline
9 & 4 &   &  & 8 & 3 &   \\  
  & 9 &   &  &   & 8 &   \\ \hline
  &   &   &  & 10 & 0 &   \\  
  &   &   &  &   & 5 &    \\ 
  &   &   &  &   & 10 &    \\ \hline
 \end{array}

Using $2a+3b+5c=30$, fill in values of $c$. Many possibilities will be crossed out due to $\# 4$. $\# 2$, $\# 3$, will be automatically true.
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c} \hline
a & b & c &  & a & b & c \\ \hline
1 & 1 & \quad 5 \quad \color{green}\checkmark  &  & 0 & 0 & \quad 6 \quad \color{green}\checkmark  \\  
  & 6 & \quad 2 \quad \color{green}\checkmark  &  &   & 5 & \quad 3 \quad \color{green}\checkmark  \\  
  &   &   &  &   & 10 & \quad 0 \quad \color{green}\checkmark  \\ \hline
3 & 3 &  \quad 3 \quad \color{green}\checkmark &  & 2 & 2 & \quad 4 \quad \color{green}\checkmark  \\  
  & 8 & \color{red}\times  &  &   & 7 & \quad 1 \quad \color{green}\checkmark  \\ \hline
5 & 0 & \quad 4 \quad \color{green}\checkmark  &  & 4 & 4 & \quad 2 \quad \color{green}\checkmark  \\  
  & 5 & \quad 1 \quad \color{red}\times  &  &   & 9 & \color{red}\times  \\  
  & 10 & \color{red}\times  &  &   &   &   \\ \hline
7 & 2 & \quad 2 \quad \color{red}\times  &  &  6 & 1 & \quad 3 \quad \color{green}\checkmark \\  
  & 7 & \color{red}\times  &  &   &  6 &  \color{red}\times \\ \hline
9 & 4 & \color{red}\times  &  & 8 & 3 & \color{red}\times  \\  
  & 9 & \color{red}\times  &  &   & 8 & \color{red}\times  \\ \hline
  &   &   &  & 10 & 0 & \quad 2 \quad \color{red}\times  \\  
  &   &   &  &   & 5 & \color{red}\times  \\ 
  &   &   &  &   & 10 & \color{red}\times  \\ \hline
 \end{array}

There are $11$ valid solutions.